# parseCSV PHP adding extra CR (\r) at end of rows when using save() or output()

Tags: php

This should be a pretty easy one.  I am trying to write CSV from a 2D array using

```
    $csv = new parseCSV();
    $csv->save('test.csv', $ex,false,$headers);
```

I am using this: https://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/

I'm getting :

```
    LAKE GEORGE HAT,LAKE GEORGE HATCHERY,43.230934255293,-73.668372632705\r
    \r\n
    BATH HATCHERY,BATH HATCHERY,42.373881127958,-77.284257679631\r
    \r\n
```

I thought the issue was in a stray \r the last data column, so I added

```
    $ex[$i]['LON'] = trim($ll['lon']);
```

to my loop.  But the result is still every other row being blank in excel.  I am sure I must be missing something.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I still didn't really find out where the extra CR is coming from but I managed to fix the issue by setting the class property "linefeed" in parsecsv.lib.php from:

```
    # used by unparse(), save(), and output() functions
var $linefeed = "\r\n";
```

to:

```
    # used by unparse(), save(), and output() functions
var $linefeed = "\n";
```

This seemed to fix this issue in excel as the extra \r is now followed by a plain \n.